# Do the tug of war rules have a typo? ("Or" vs. "nor")

Tags: conjunctions, negation, or-nor

The [Official Tug of War Rules](http://www.tug-o-war.asn.au/towrules.pdf) (link is PDF, [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aDLu38o18BysJ%3awww.tug-o-war.asn.au/towrules.pdf+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgWqOLkvWFtszNJYLR6nUMQDMnXp-zv3u_EGaR3mHXiJEqN0Tu9h203-YthTUEdkTPR59l7P9GWn5VTGubT1OEpVWGqq1bV0WDHSa9h_a4SFmMNk5oyZTeEhvspsV764eGLigCT&sig=AHIEtbQVV-KUOQrpLiEfUtMpZN3AVpXM2w) is Google quickview link) say:

> The rope must not be less than 10 centimetres (100 mm), **or** more than
>   12.5 centimetres (125 mm) in circumference...

Since it's declaring a negation, shouldn't it be nor?

Comment: I would write it as *not less than 10 centimetres...* in which case *nor* would be usual and better (I don't believe 'right' is suitable). Altering the word order seems to make either possible, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 8):

**Nor** is generally only used in conjunction with **neither**, so you could rewrite the sentence as:

> The rope must be **neither** less than 10 centimetres (100 mm), **nor** more than 12.5 centimetres (125 mm) in circumference...

... but that's not necessary.  The sentence is just fine as it stands.

You're parsing the sentence as if "not" and "or" were in opposition.  They're not: "less" and "more" are the alternatives here.  It might make more sense if you strip it down to:

> ...must not be less or more

Comment: votes are currently tied 5 to 5. can any voters add input?

Comment: This is correct, although "nor" *could* be used just as well.

Answer (score 5):

Although there are some people who are afraid to use *nor* without *neither*, that seems silly to me. I would certainly have written *nor* there in your example sentence. The OED supports this very sort of thing in its sense 3a for [**nor** *conj.<sup>1</sup>* (and *adv*.)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/128228), which is:

> **3a.** Following a word or phrase which is negated with *not*, *never*, etc.

Here are two of its citations for that sense:

> - **1934**   ‘M. J. Farrell’ *Devoted Ladies* i. 36   
>   One must not be harsh to him, nor must an author betray too great a knowledge.
> - **2002**   K. Matinuddin *Nuclearization of S. Asia* x. 200
>      Non-Nuclear Weapon States..who are party to the Treaty, undertake not to receive nuclear weapons nor to manufacture them.

See? Perfectly natural. Your sentence involves an instance following *not*, which is directly covered above. I would have used *nor*.

There are other senses of *nor* without a corresponding *neither*, but I shall not list those here.

Nor shall I list them down here.

Nor here, either. :)

Comment: I would say that *nor* is good for separating independent verb phrases, as in your two examples: "one must not be / nor must an author betray" and "not to receive / nor to manufacture".  I still say it's not a good fit in a sentence with a single verb, such as "must not be less or more".

Comment: But DelvarWorld is asking whether _or_ is OK, not whether _nor_ is OK!

Comment: I don't know what to believe anymore

Comment: DelvarWorld asked whether there was a typo in the original sentence.  I say NO; the sentence is fine as it stands, and in fact reads more naturally in its current form than if "or" were changed to "nor".  @tchrist appears to be saying that YES, the current form is wrong.  My feeling is that - whether using "nor" here is good grammar or not - it would break the implied parallelism of the sentence.

Comment: Although you might choose to use *nor* instead of *or*, there is nothing really wrong with the sentence as written.