# Using "nor" at the end of a list begun with "no"

Tags: lists, disjunction, neither-nor, or-nor

Which is correct?

> - "The book has no marks, tears, wrinkles or writing."
> - "The book has no marks, tears, wrinkles nor writing."

(I understand the use of neither/nor and either/or.) In this case, I thought the first sentence "no/or" was correct, but was told that "no/nor" was the correct usage. Can you help?

Comment: Either is acceptable, and both occur.

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/a/106796, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/53728, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3623, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30075, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/73219, amongst others many and varied.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have gotten it wrong, "The book has no marks, tears, wrinkles or writing." is right, for you have written, already, a negative conjunction; 'no'.

Comment: You can also use *nor* after a negated series.  It is not reserved for only two alternatives.